# How to dynamically create routes?

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

I'm trying to dynamically add routes to my api by iterating over an array of objects called route groups. A route group can have many routes.

Here are my types (the RouterContext type comes from Oak middleware framework):

```
// routes/mod.ts
type Route = {
  method: string;
  path: string;
  handler: (ctx: RouterContext) => Promise<void>;
};

export type RouteGroup = {
  group: {
    prefix: string;
  };
  routes: Route[];
};
```

Here is my router class:

```
export class Router {
  // imported Oak's Router class as oakRouter
  router: oakRouter;

  constructor() {
    this.router = new oakRouter({ prefix: "/api" });
  }

  register(): void {
    this._createRoutes(routeGroups);
  }

  private _createRoutes(routeGroups: RouteGroup[]) {
    routeGroups.forEach(({ group, routes }) => {
      routes.forEach(({ method, path, handler }) => {
        this.router[method](group.prefix + path, handler); // <-- this.router[method] is underlined with an error
      });
    });
  }
}
```

A typical route looks like this:

```
router.get("/", (ctx) => {
    ctx.response.body = "Welcome to My Oak App.";
});
```

But when I use bracket notation to dynamically add the http method that I want to use in _createRoutes(), I get the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Router<RouteParams, Record<string, any>>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Router<RouteParams, Record<string, any>>'.deno-ts(7053)
```

How do I change the method property on the Route type from a string into a valid index signature? Is that even what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and least type-safe approach would be to cast your router function to `any` if you're confident you know better than the TypeScript compiler:

```
(this.router[method] as any)(group.prefix + path, handler);
```

or

```
(<any>this.router[method])(group.prefix + path, handler);
```

This bypasses a lot of type-checking which usually isn't what we want.

---

Another approach is to use a type guard for each method supported by Oak `Router` (e.g. via a `switch` statement) which is type-safe but does duplicate some code:

```
const args = [group.prefix + path, handler] as const;
switch (method) {
  case "all":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "delete":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "get":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "head":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "options":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "patch":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "post":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
  case "put":
    this.router[method](...args);
    break;
}
```

---

A third option is to enumerate the supported method function names in `Route.method` and then tell the TypeScript compiler to treat all of the functions as the same function type (picking any of the function names, e.g. `get`):

```
type Route = {
  method:
    | "all"
    | "delete"
    | "get"
    | "head"
    | "options"
    | "patch"
    | "post"
    | "put";
  path: string;
  handler: (ctx: RouterContext) => Promise<void>;
};
```

Then inside of `_createRoutes`:

```
(this.router[method] as oakRouter["get"])(group.prefix + path, handler);
```

This is more type-safe than the first approach but less type-safe than the second approach.

---

P.S. I suggest renaming `oakRouter` to `OakRouter`. Class and type names typically start with an upper case letter in JavaScript/TypeScript.